# CMake FetchContent with HTTP redirection

Tags: cmake

Trying to download a public file from SharePoint via CMake's FetchContent.
My URL is like the following:

```
https://myorg.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/myfolder/EdajXJq3IV5HrSs9bKhEFoYByaMZHBYHyftA9GKLAGZ5wA?e=QPdu1N&Download=1
```

Note I added `&Download=1` to the path given by SharePoint to access the file directly. However, my link gets redirect every time I use it. I'm able to download the file using `wget` & `curl`:

1. `curl -v -L --cookie tmp.cookie 'https://link.from.above' --output myfile.txt`
2. `wget 'https://link.from.above'`

Now trying do the same using CMake:

```
FetchContent_Declare(${MY_TARGET}
    URL ${FILE_URL}
)
```

But that doesn't work. I guess it has something to do with redirection / cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. We are currently using the following workaround (which is far from perfect):

1. Check if the file exists in a specific location in the source directory
2. If it does not exist, download the file using curl
3. Pass the path to the downloaded file to FetchContent_Declare

If anyone has better ideas, I would like to hear them!